# How do I integrate with respect to one variable when an integrand has many variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate the following integrand:

```
(μ*a*curr/4 π)*((x - a*Cos[ϕ] + y - a*Sin[ϕ])/
 ((x - a*Cos[ϕ])^2 + (y - a*Sin[ϕ])^2)^(3/2))
```

with the following constants:

```
a = 1
μ = 4*π*10^-7
curr = 1
```

The command I typed in Mathematica was:

```
Integrate[(μ*a*curr/4 π)*((x - a*Cos[ϕ] + y - a*Sin[ϕ])/
 ((x - a*Cos[ϕ])^2 + (y - a*Sin[ϕ])^2)^(3/2)), {ϕ, 0, π/2}]
```

The output was:

```
π/2500000
```

Why is my output a constant and not an expression with $x$ and $y$ as variables?

Comment: $\pi/2500000$ is the value of $\mu_0$;  it would have been printed as part of your output if you didn't put a semicolon after the line where you defined it.  Are you sure that the code actually finished?  It has taken at least a few minutes on my machine.

Comment: It took about 10 minutes for Mathematica to return the integral (unevaluated) on my machine.  (I did tell it to assume that $x$ and $y$ were positive numbers, so your results may vary.)

Comment: I added semicolons to silence the unwanted output. Additionally, I waited awhile and it did indeed spit out a result. the result was --I WILL POST IN NEXT REPLY-- which is unexpected because I was looking for a function of x and y. For context, I am trying to compute the magnetic field for any point in space from an arc (with a constant radius 'a' from the origin). Textbooks usually just find the magnetic field at a specific point (usually the origin) and not a generalized function. I wanted to find the generalized function.

Comment: The output was (\[Pi]^2 (2 - 
    I AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, 3 - 2 Sqrt[2], 
      3 + 2 Sqrt[2]] + 
    8 I AppellF1[1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 3/2, 3 - 2 Sqrt[2], 3 + 2 Sqrt[2]]) + 
 I Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(3/2) (Gamma[3/4]^2 - 4 Gamma[5/4]^2))/10000000

Comment: When I remove the restrictions on `x` and `y` I do get (after about 10 minutes) an expression involving `x` and `y` and various `AppellF1` functions.  Be sure to clear your computer's memory before running the code.